# Disable reminder on an appointment created with EWS

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices

When I create an appointment with EWS, Outlook displays a reminder 15 minutes before the event. I want to disable this, and there is an option for it:

```
appointment.IsReminderSet = false;
```

but it simply does not work. In Outlook the event displays as "Reminder: None", but the reminder is sent nonetheless 15 minutes prior.

[image: Reminder looks to be set to None]

I also tried setting the `ReminderMinutesBeforeStart` property to -1 (which caused Outlook to not be able to display the invitation) or 0 and `ReminderDueBy` to past dates, but none of this helped, the reminder is still sent.

How can I really disable the reminder?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is not enough to set `IsReminderSet` to `false` because the sender user's setting can overwrite it. You have to search for *Options > Calendar > Default reminders* and turn that off too:

[image: Turn Default reminders off in Outlook]

You need to set this in Outlook for the sender user AND also use the option for the appointment described in the question:

```
appointment.IsReminderSet = false;
```

Only one is not enough, both needs to be set.